# ¿Cómo hacer un bucle en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Disculpen que no he puesto código pero he buscado y no he podido acercarme al tema. tengo una tabla que consta de: id, nombre, cargo, idjefe. este ultimo se encuentra incluido en la misma tabla pero quiero hacer un bucle que me muestre la jerarquía de cada persona ejemplo: la jerarquía se encuentra compuesta por (de menos a mas): auditor=>supervisor=>coordinador=>director y el bucle que necesito es que me traiga el jefe inmediato de cada persona  hasta el superior que en este caso es el director; he puesto una imagen con el resultado de lo que quiero que me consulte.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cual es tu sistema de BD: SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postresql...?

Comment: lo estoy trabajando en MySQL

Comment: @RafaelPereira entiendo que quieres hacer una busqueda recursiva, ya que el campo `Idjefe` relaciona a un dato dentro de la misma tabla, dicho esto, no es mejor hacer este recorrido en tu código y no en la consulta SQL?

Comment: Te faltan detalles sobre lo que quieres: *el bucle que necesito es que me traiga el jefe inmediato de cada persona hasta el superior que en este caso es el director* ... ¿ **por qué medio se organiza ese orden de superioridad** donde el `Director` es el cargo más alto? Tampoco el ejemplo que muestras es del todo claro, por ejemplo: ¿Qué es `Paul Contancio` **de sí mismo** para que aparezca en su propio resultado? ¿Acaso `Jeyson Vargas` **se supervisa a sí mismo**?... En definitiva, tu pregunta no está planteada de una forma del todo clara ni el ejemplo que pones tampoco.

Comment: Y sigo: ¿cómo es que `Laura Rodríguez` ocupa el cargo de `Director` que según tú es lo máximo y aparece como supervisada por `Jeyson Vargas`???? O, ¿es que hay dos Laura Rodríguez?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien lo que quieres, yo haría un re-ordenamiento del diseño de mi base de datos, con varias tablas:

- `empleado`     : para manejar a todos los empleados y sus cargos
- `cargo`        : para manejar los cargos
- `gestion`      : para manejar las *relaciones*  entre empleados. O sea, quién es jefe de quién y en qué sentido lo es
- `tipo_gestion` : para manejar el tipo de mando que un empleado ejerce sobre otro y la prioridad de ese mando en el organigrama. Esta tabla permitirá ordenar según la importancia desde director hasta el último de la empresa.

Basándonos en ese esquema, podríamos obtener lo que quieres con una simple consulta como esta:

```
SELECT 
    es.empleado_nom jefe, 
    MAX(tg.tipo_gestion) tipo_gestion, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(ei.empleado_nom) subalternos 
FROM tipo_gestion_20180801 tg 
    INNER JOIN gestion_20180801 g ON tg.tipo_gestion_id=g.tipo_gestion_id 
    INNER JOIN empleado_20180801 ei ON g.empleado_id=ei.empleado_id
    INNER JOIN empleado_20180801 es ON g.superior_id=es.empleado_id
GROUP BY es.empleado_id
ORDER BY max(tg.orden);
```

Un resultado hipotético sería:

```
jefe                tipo_gestion      subalternos
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Alberto López       Director          Pablo Contancio,Jeyson Vargas,Andrea Villamizar
Carolina Montes     Coordinador       Jorge Rincón,Laura Acevedo
```

Lo que expresan los resultados, *hipotéticos* subrayo, es que:

- `Alberto López` es el `Director` de `Pablo Contancio,Jeyson Vargas,Andrea Villamizar`
- `Carolina Montes` es `Coordinadora` de `Jorge Rincón,Laura Acevedo`

Quiero hacer constar que un diseño como el tuyo se podría **complicar**. Imaginemos un escenario en el que un empleado puede ser sub-alterno de dos o más jefes en áreas diferentes de la empresa.  O que un empleado es `sub-alterno` de alguien y a la vez es jefe de otros... para todos esos casos complicados, la tabla `gestion` ofrece una flexibilidad que se adapta a un manejo claro y fácil de lo que sea.

No sé si la respuesta es exactamente lo que quieres, pero al menos pienso que abre un horizonte diferente para este tipo de casos.

Espero te sea de utilidad. Más abajo te dejo el enlace con los datos *hipotéticos*  que he usado para hacer mis demostraciones.  Los puedes modificar en rextester y hacer pruebas sobre ese modelo de datos o modificarlo a conveniencia.

---

### Prueba de concepto

<kbd>**[VER DEMOSTRACIÓN EN REXTESTER](http://rextester.com/KBDUZ76165)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow amigo, encantado con tus contribuciones, simplemente genial.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de el motor de base de datos que estes usando si el lenguaje soportado es Transact SQL como la mayoría, podría crear una función escalar recursiva que resuelva esa Consulta y llamarlo en el SELECT, no especificas que sintaxis usas y yo no recuerdo mucho de TSQL por lo que toma este snippet como un pseudocodigo.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetListOfBosses(@id Nvarchar(50)) RETURNS STRING

AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @id INTEGER
   DECLARE @jefeid INTEGER
   DELCARE @jefeslist STRING

   set @jefeid = select id FROM employeeTbl where ID = @id
   set @jefename = select nombre FROM employeeTbl where ID = @id


   IF @jefeid != NULL
     @jefeslist = @jefename + GetListOfBosses(@jefeid)
   ELSE
     @jefeslist = @jefename
   END

   RETURN @jefeslist
END
```

Y se llamaría algo asi

```
SELECT id, name, GetListOfBosses(id) FROM employeeTbl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si la cantidad de "niveles" es fija y no son demasiados, según tu ejemplo, no más de 4, podrías usar una consulta plana, haciendo un `JOIN` recursivo sobre la misma tabla:

```
SELECT  CONCAT( T1.nombre,
                IFNULL(CONCAT(',',T2.nombre),''),
                IFNULL(CONCAT(',',T3.nombre),''),  
                IFNULL(CONCAT(',',T4.nombre),'')
        ) 
        from TablaEmpleados T1
        LEFT JOIN TablaEmpleados T2
           ON T2.ID = T1.idjefe AND T1.ID <> T1.idjefe
        LEFT JOIN TablaEmpleados T3
           ON T3.ID = T2.idjefe AND T2.ID <> T2.idjefe
        LEFT JOIN TablaEmpleados T4
           ON T4.ID = T3.idjefe AND T3.ID <> T3.idjefe
```

Nota: La condición de `T(n).ID <> T(n).idjefe` es para no seguir avanzando si llegamos a la directora.